# Reshaping dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe for my experiment result :
[image]

How can I reshape it to look like this table :

[image]

Comment: Could you share data as text, not images, as well as the code you've tried so far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341) for specifics, as well as [mre] in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the data you've provided you should be able to use `.unstack()` to do this:

```py
print(df['counts'].unstack(level=['Model_1', 'Winloss']))
```